# Why does this part of the code in App.js not work? (I make a search filter)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some list of names that I take from the array using the Fetch method, and at the moment I want to implement a search filter, but when I inserted the resetData () method into my componentDidMount, I got this error:
[image]

this is my code in the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-cherry-66e9p

what should I fix in my code for my search filter to work? maybe the reason is not only in this line? componentDidMount () must be there, as without it other things will not work in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `function` infront of your function name resetData

```
 async function resetData()  {
    const response = await fetch("/data/mass.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({
        data
    });
```

This will solve the error for you. But this will create a scope issue so i suggest this instead.

```
const resetData = async () =>  {
    const response = await fetch("/data/mass.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({
        data
    });
```

Also since this function is inside `componentDidMount()`. You can't call it seperately like you are trying to inside render so i suggest you get this function outside componentDidMount and call it inside componentDidMount Like -

`const data = await this.resetData();`

I guess this works as you intended?

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-albattani-7nyxt

EDIT: I edited the code inside the codesandbox so that it works according to your needs.

Comment: thank you very much, but there is one problem when I type in a second name such as "Todd" it does not display it empty. And to filter the second name you need to reload the page. How to solve this problem?
Try typing a different name in the sandbox and see what the problem is

Comment: @vrm111 I edited the code so that it works. I changed some logic to do so. Check it out.

Comment: and why do you need this check? 
```const arr = this.state.data.group && this.state.data.group.first ? this.state.data.group.first : this.state.data;```

Comment: @vrm111 that was your logic, I didn't feel right to change it.